# Retrieving Records If Their Association Exists in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a User model that has a has_one association with a UserInfo model.  I'd like to be able to find all Users that have a UserInfo model.  I've tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to work in Rails 3.2:

```
Users.joins(:user_infos).where("user_info IS NOT NULL")
Users.joins(:user_infos).where("user_infos.id IS NOT NULL")
```

In each case, I just get back all of the users even though, currently, only 1 of my 1000 users actually has a UserInfo associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know the response:

in your `user.rb` write this

```
 def self.available
  joins(:user_infos).uniq
end
```

Joining the `user_infos` association will remove `Users` without any `user_infos` ... SQL is doing your work here.

Now where You want those `Users` with having `user_info`, you can get them by using

```
 User.available
```